# My CPU clock speed is changing constantly. Is it normal?

Tags: intel, cpufreq, cpuinfo

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop, and whenever I run

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "MHz"
```

I get varying speeds. I thought that clockspeed is a fixed property, which can be under clocked or overclocked. But is this behaviour normal?

[image]

Comment: It is normal. It depends on load.

Comment: @Pilot6 So how can I find the max?

Comment: Run `sudo dmidecode | grep  "Max Speed"`. But if CPU is overclocked, it won't show correct info.

Comment: And please, do not post sceenshots of badly coloured text over transparent backgrounds. Just copy-paste it and save us all the trouble.

Comment: This is called "dynamic overclocking". An example is the [Intel® Turbo Boost Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the [CPU governor](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling#Scaling_governors) does - observe the usage and adjust frequency accordingly. [CPU frequency scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_frequency_scaling) is a pretty standard technique for power saving. There are tools to manage frequency scaling, `cpupower` from `linux-tools-common` is one such.

To look at current governor settings, you can inspect the folders in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq`. For example, the available maximum frequency of my CPUs:

```
$ tail /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq 
==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq <==
3301000

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq <==
3301000

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq <==
3301000

==> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq <==
3301000
```

The governor parameters might have a different (lower) maximum value, stored in the corresponding `scaling_max_freq` files.